# GWTBootstrap3 components rendering incorrectly in IE11

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwtbootstrap3

My page elements should appear in all browsers as follows:

[image]

I can only achieve this in IE11 by having the dev tools open during page load, otherwise the page generates as the following:

[image]

Summary

- no rounded corners on box elements
- no column alignment (bootstrap class "col-lg-2" on
  all label elements)
- Legend formatting not added
- general alignment off
- no smooth accordion transition - open or closed

This issue is only with IE11, the site works in chrome, firefox and even Safari without any additional plumbing. I have found some IE fixes on SO, but so far none of them have worked:

***.html** - add meta information to use Edge engine

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<html>
  <head>
    <!--[if IE]>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
    <![endif]-->

    ... html continues with rest of head
```

***.js** - to prevent undefined console from blocking processing

```
 if(!window.console) {
            console.log(item);
        }
```

I have been sure to use Ctrl  F5 when reloading the page for testing, and have also restarted devmode to see if that makes a difference. I have also confirmed that the site is not running in compatibility mode by looking in the compatability settings.

Looking through the logs I can see that when the page loads with dev tools closed, the binding is carried out using *user.agent=ie8*, whilst with devtools open, the binding property is *user.agent=gecko1_8*. **I thought IE11 should always use the gecko1_8 permutation - why could this not be happening?**

(using GWT Version 2.7)

Comment: have just discovered that using <!DOCTYPE> should no longer be used [Specifying legacy document modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), however removing it does not have any affect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will be of any help.
We are using GWT (2.8, but I think it also worked with 2.7 in the past).
With GWT-Bootstrap3 (https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3/gwtbootstrap3) without any problems in IE11. I am not sure you are using the same bootstrap library ?

Anyway. We added the following line in our html file (as the first line of the head tag) :

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
```

I can not really remember how I came up with this line, but the version history states : "It is now possible to use IE11 in compatibility mode"

So it has to do something with fixing something in IE-11, using GWT and bootstrap 3 :-)

Comment: this is correct - altough I still don't fully understand why, adding `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge">` to my *.html file (as I had in my initial question) AND removing a 2nd meta tag for `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` further down the header resulted in the correct gecko binding being used for IE11 - thanks!

Comment: I don't think you need to remove that second line. We also have a <meta charset="utf-8"> line, and a <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> line...... The x-ua-compatible line forces the browser to use the IE-10 renderer. Otherwise it does something based on some checkboxes hidden somewhere in the overload of checkboxes of the IE configuration.

Comment: correct again, the problem with that I initially posted in the question was most likely the conditional statement surrounding the meta tag - "if IE" is not supported in Windows 10 or higher; [Conditional comments are no longer supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx)